# Multiple Settings for One Monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, amd-vision

I have my monitor set to the way I like it, it shows colors accurately and not overly bright (white doesn't blind me). However I edit photos for the web and this is great for my screen but I have noticed when looking at other screens my photos will at times looked washed out and not a good presentation. If I manually change my monitor settings to be brighter (and a few other tweaks) I can replicate the look of other monitors close enough to help prevent washed out/blown out photos. Here is the issue, I need to be able to change settings between the two fairly easily. To manually set my monitor for one then back to the other can be time consuming and a pain to set right every time.

I would like to be able to preset certain settings (in software) that I can quickly switch between by pressing <kbd>hotkeys</kbd>   or clicking shortcut on my desktop. I have an AMD video card and have attempted to use the AMD VISION Engine Control Center to add presets then tweak the settings for each. However when I switch between the presets the settings are the same.

How do I build presets using the VISION Engine Control Center that actually works (maybe I misunderstand what it is saving?) or is there a way to do this in Windows 7 or *free* software that actually works decently for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do this using AMD Catalyst Control Center.

> Settings that are saved within a preset are determined based on the page currently shown in the Control Center application window. Therefore, it is important that you navigate to the appropriate page before creating a preset.
>
> Creating Presets:
>
> 1. Navigate to the desired page and apply the changes that you want to save.
> 2. Under the Presets group in the navigation pane, click Add Preset.
> 3. In the Preset dialog box that opens, expand the following groups, and provide the appropriate information.
>
> Applying Presets:
>
> Control Center Application Window—Under the Presets group in the navigation pane, click the preset that you want to apply. Alternatively, click Manage Presets; in the Manage Presets dialog box that opens, select the desired preset, and then click Apply.
>
> • Windows Start Menu—Click the Windows Start button followed by the appropriate Control Center option. In the Presets folder, click the desired preset